# Why manifest file is not available in my puppet master

Tags: puppet

I'm very new with puppet. For initial setup, I have configured puppet master and agent in my Ubuntu 18.04.

The configuration has been completed and I can see cert has been exchanged between master and slave.

But, I didn't find the puppet manifest folders in the below location
/etc/puppet/

expecting following folder 
/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

Can somebody explain why the manifest folder was missing under /etc/puppet/

More information:
Puppet --version : 5.4.0

A package is being used- 
wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet6-release-bionic.deb

Do i need to use - puppetlabs-release-precise.deb instead of puppet6-release-bionic.deb? Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 3):

The default location of the main/site manifest is  `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp`, according to [the documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.4/dirs_manifest.html).